# AngularJS factory function cannot access a locally stored cache variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have been at this for over 10 hours at this point. It does not make sense to me. I desperately need clarification on what I'm doing wrong. Below is a simple factory function that makes an AJAX call for a JSON file. There are no async. data issues and everything just works. The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to save the returned result and access it later. If the variable is populated, I don't then have to make a second AJAX call, I can simple grab the contents of a local variable. I realize there are other ways of doing this, but I'm particular to using this factory method.

```
storyDataAsFactory.$inject = ['$log', '$http', '$q'];

angular.module('ccsApp').factory('storyDataAsFactory', storyDataAsFactory);

function storyDataAsFactory($log, $http, $q) {
    var storiesCache = [];

    function getStories(url) {
        url = url || '';

        if (url !== '') {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            alert('inside getStories, length of storiesCache = ' + storiesCache.length); // this is always zero! Why?

            //determine if ajax call has already occurred;
            //if so, data exists in cache as local var
            if (storiesCache.length !== 0) {
                $log.info('Returning stories from cache.');

                deferred.resolve(storiesCache);
                return deferred.promise;
            }

            $http({method:'GET', url:url})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            $log.error('(within storyDataAsFactory) Failed to retrieve stories: URL was undefined.');
        }
    }

    return {
        stories: storiesCache,

        getStories: function(url) {
            alert('inside return factory object, length of stories = ' + this.stories.length);
            //getStories returns a promise so that routeProvider
            //will instantiate the controller when resolved
            return getStories(url);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why are you using $q to make $http a promise when its a promise already.

Comment: B/c I'm using a routeProvider in my config block to wait for the data to return before my app loads. It's a part of my resolve object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a promise. I have not ran the code below, but this is the idea:

```
angular.module('ccsApp').service('storyDataAsFactory', storyDataAsService);

function storyDataAsService($log, $http, $q) {
    var storiesCache = [];

    function getStories(url) {

        url = url || '';

        if (url !== '') {
            alert('inside getStories, length of storiesCache = ' + storiesCache.length); // this is always zero! Why?
            if (storiesCache.length == 0) {
               return $http({method:'GET', url:url});
            } else {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(storiesCache);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        } else {
            $log.error('(within storyDataAsFactory) Failed to retrieve stories: URL was undefined.');
        }
    }

    return {
        getStories: function(url) {
            return getStories(url).then(function(stories) {
                // Do whatever
                return stories;
            });
        }
    };
}


storyDataAsService.getStories().then(function(stories) {
    $scope.stories = stories
})
```

Comment: I'm already doing this in my config block. This is not the solution.